# unable to get push notifications, unauthorized webhook call back error 401

Tags: push-notification, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

Not able to establish watch channel. getting unauthorized push notification error 401. Done all required settings for web_hook to work.added domain in domain verification tab. Stuck here for weeks. plz help me out. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should have a ssl certificate as push notification only work on https:// you can read all about the requirement here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push

but the thing missing in the above link is you shoul have the authentication token set on the callback url ( similar to that when you set before calling a google API.. ) and dont forget to take access token from database (assuming that you had it stored at the time of authentication) as system will not read it from session on callback url.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got what I wanted in the link. But how to handle the callback. Do i need to use jetty, which is similar handling callback for getting **code** which is again used for getting tokenresponse in Quickstart.java?

Comment: no jetty is not required, on the callback url the token must be set. If you are doing i in php it will be done by a function "$client->setAccessToken($access_token);"

Comment: I'm using java. Then what we will use to get to know google sever has done POST on push notifications callback url.

Comment: just set the token on the call backurl, read the notification headers then write all the data in a file..
when ever the notification will be send the file will be updated ..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how to listen for the incoming messages for reading notification headers.?

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-request-header-in-java/ have a look at this...
this may help.........

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this value to the headers of your request:

- "Authorization: Bearer user_token"

You can get user token with a GET Google_Http_Request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token

**PHP example to get Google token:**

Use [Google APIs PHP Client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

```
$TokenRequest = new Google_Http_Request(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token", 
    "GET"
);
$Token = $Client->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($TokenRequest);
```